# In characterizing finiteness via $\mathsf{AC}_\omega$, do we need to use large sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

The usual proof that "Dedekind finite = finite" from $\mathsf{ZF+AC_\omega}$ goes by, given a Dedekind-infinite set $X$, applying countable choice to the sequence $(X^n)_{n\in\omega}$. It just occurred to me that I don't know whether using such "increasingly large" sets is actually needed here.

Specifically, given an infinite set $X$, say that an **$X$-small sequence** is an $\omega$-indexed sequence of nonempty sets $(A_i)_{i\in\omega}$ such that, for some finite $n$, no $A_i$ surjects onto $X^n$. My question is the following:

> Is the theory $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "There is an infinite Dedekind-finite $X$ such that every $X$-small sequence has a choice function" consistent?

A related question is whether $\mathsf{ZFA}$ + "The class $\mathscr{A}$ of atoms is an infinite Dedekind-finite set" + "Every $\mathscr{A}$-small sequence has a choice function" is consistent. At a glance I **don't** think [Pincus' embedding theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137462/intuition-behind-pincus-injectively-bounded-statements) (let alone Jech/Sochor) would apply here, so a positive answer wouldn't address the actual question, but it would still be interesting.

Comment: Do the embedding theorems not apply because the class of atoms is not necessarily a set?

Comment: @JamesHanson No (and note that I've stated that the class of atoms *is* a set in the case I'm interested in), the issue is that the embedding theorems only work if the statement in question is sufficiently syntactically "nice." And, at a glance, I don't think this one is (although I could be wrong, I'm notoriously bad at this sort of thing).

Comment: Ah, it's because surjection-based bounds on cardinality are wonky. In particular, '$X$-small sets' could have arbitrarily high rank, right?

Comment: Add $\omega\times\omega$ Cohen reals with the permutation group $S_\omega\wr S_\omega$ and with the filter generated by fixing finitely many 'blocks', then, I strongly suspect for no particularly good reason, you may be able to prove that any set surjects onto the amorphous set or blocks (up to a finite error) or can be well-ordered. Since the power set of an amorphous set is Dedekind-finite, this means there is no infinite sequence of distinct subsets; and so one may be able to deduce that any such sequence must be actually finitely many sets rotating around, or have a well-orderable union.

Comment: (Again, just a strategy for someone who wants to have a go at this.)